# MacOS disable bluetooth device auto-connect

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of Sennheiser PXC 550 headphones which are connected to both my Macbook and iPhone. I am trying to fix a very weird bug that manifests with the following steps:

1. Listen to music on my Mac with headphones
2. Close the lid *while music is playing* and put my Mac to sleep
3. Turn off headphones
4. Turn on headphones (next day)

At this point once they auto connect to my iPhone and Mac they become unusable on my phone unless I wake up the Mac (which might be out of convenient reach).

I've tried to resolve this by adding a script that disconnects the headphones before my mac sleeps. Unfortunately my headphones still auto-connect once they are turned on and end up in the same zombie state. I tried 
`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist IgnoredDevices -array-add 'my serial'` and then restarted my laptop but they still auto-connect despite being in the ignored list.

Is there a way to make sure my headphones don't auto-connect while not disabling bluetooth completely (I need to wake with keyboard)? Any other workarounds to this issue are welcome.